# String Searching - CodeEval - Trouble identifying cases that break code

Tags: string, dynamic-programming

*This is NOT an active contest/competition problem.

I've made major head way on the following problem (and I've scored 92.5/100), but I've been furiously scratching my head for the past few hours as to what cases I'm not considering and thus missing.

Here is the problem statement:

You are given two strings. Determine if the second string is a substring of the first (Do NOT use any substr type library function). The second string may contain an asterisk(*) which should be treated as a regular expression i.e. matches zero or more characters; the asterisk can be escaped by a \ char in which case it should be interpreted as a regular '*' character. To summarize: the first string can contain the alphabet, digits and '*', and the second string can contain the alphabet, digits, \ and '*'.

Here below is my dynamic programming approach:

```
private static String REGEX0 = "\\*";
private static String REGEX1 = "\\\\\\*";
private static String REPLACE = "#";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(args[0]);
    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;
    while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
        line = line.trim();
        if (line.isEmpty()) continue;
        String[] sar = line.split(",");
        Pattern pattern0 = Pattern.compile(REGEX0);
        Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile(REGEX1);
        Matcher matcher0 = pattern0.matcher(sar[0]);
        Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(sar[1]);
        sar[0] = matcher0.replaceAll(REPLACE);
        sar[1] = matcher1.replaceAll(REPLACE);
        System.out.println(find(sar[0], sar[1]));
    }
}

private static boolean find(String r, String c) {
    int[][] match = new int[r.length() + 1][c.length() + 1];
    for (int i = 1; i <= r.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= c.length(); j++) {
            if (r.charAt(i - 1) == c.charAt(j - 1)) {
                match[i][j] = match[i - 1][j - 1] + 1;
            } else if (c.charAt(j - 1) == '*') {
                if (match[i - 1][j - 1] == 0) {
                    match[i][j] = Math.max(match[i - 1][j], match[i][j - 1]);
                } else {
                    match[i][j] = match[i - 1][j - 1] + 1;
                }
            }
            if (match[i][j] == c.length()) return true;
        }
    }
    return c.length() > r.length() && match[r.length()][c.length()] == r.length();
}
```

Here are a few inputs and the associated answers, which my code currently correctly produces:

So*eaE,C*E
blah**blah*,bl*h\*
Hello,ell
This is good, is
CodeEval,C*Eval
Old,Young

false
true
true
true
true
false

CodeEval doesn't let you see the testcases. So I'd appreciate someone helping me figure out the testcase(s) that are breaking my code, so I can fix my code logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st String, 2nd String, Actual Result, Expected Result

```
*So*eaE, *JH*, false, false
*So*eaE, **, false,   true(?)
blblah*, blb*h*, true, true
blah*, blb*h*, false,  false
blah*, blb*h, false,   false
CodeEval, C*Eval, true, true
CodeEval, C*Ev*al, false, true
CodeE*val, C*Ev*al, false, false
Old, *Young*, false,       false
Old, *ung*, false,       false
Old, *l*, false,         true (?)
Old, O*l*, true,          true
Old, *d, false,            true
Old, O*, true,            true
Old, O*d, true,           true
```